# Show Multiple Routes simultaneously on same Google Map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want Google Maps to show multiple routes from multiple origins with same destinations at the same time. The destination is given as a well-defined address however the origins are comma separated strings. When I run a loop to plot all the routes on google maps for one origins one destination pair in every iteration, it overwrites the previous routes and creates a new route. I want the old route (previous origin, destination pair) to stay and the new route (new origin, destination pair) to show simultaneously on the same map. 
How do I do so without overwriting on the old route. Please help.

**Code**

```js
//directions.js
MarketInfo = [
  ["GARIAHAT KMC MARKET", "K.M.C. Market, 3rd Floor Market Complex, 212, Rash Behari Avenue Road, Hindustan Park, Gariahat, Kolkata- 700019", "MAJOR (1400SHOP + HOWKER)", "FRUITS ETC", "", "", "BARABAZAR, KOLEYMART", "HOWRAH, BAGHAJATIN", "We colllect...", "", "MANY", "Cars, Light goods...", "Within one hour", "", "", "No problems", "", "IF A UNLOADING..."]
];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Directions service (complex)</title>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #floating-panel {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 25%;
      z-index: 5;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
      line-height: 30px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    #warnings-panel {
      width: 100%;
      height: 10%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  &nbsp;
  <div id="warnings-panel"></div>
  <script src="directions.js"></script>
  <script>
    function initialize() {
      var markerArray = [];
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: {
          lat: 22.771,
          lng: 88.974
        }
      });

      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map
      });
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, map);

      var onChangeHandler = function() {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, map);
      };

      //document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
      //document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    }


    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, map) {

      for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
        markerArray[i].setMap(null);
      }

      for (pos in MarketInfo) {
        var row = MarketInfo[pos];
        // Second loop for multiple destination
        var str_array = row[7].split(',');
        for (var j = 0; j < str_array.length; j++) {
          directionsService.route({
            origin: str_array[j],
            destination: row[1],
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
          }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
              document.getElementById('warnings-panel').innerHTML = '<b>' + response.routes[0].warnings + '</b>';
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
              window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBbXta5ppMyzPmTCGNsyP-djMlSOGJ9t9o&callback=initialize">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have a single DirectionsRenderer. You need to initialize a new DirectionsRenderer for each route you want to display. So create a new DirectionsRenderer inside your calculateAndDisplayRoute function.

```js
//directions.js
MarketInfo = [
  ["GARIAHAT KMC MARKET", "K.M.C. Market, 3rd Floor Market Complex, 212, Rash Behari Avenue Road, Hindustan Park, Gariahat, Kolkata- 700019", "MAJOR (1400SHOP + HOWKER)", "FRUITS ETC", "", "", "BARABAZAR, KOLEYMART", "HOWRAH, BAGHAJATIN", "We colllect...", "", "MANY", "Cars, Light goods...", "Within one hour", "", "", "No problems", "", "IF A UNLOADING..."]
];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Directions service (complex)</title>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #floating-panel {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 25%;
      z-index: 5;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
      line-height: 30px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    #warnings-panel {
      width: 100%;
      height: 10%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  &nbsp;
  <div id="warnings-panel"></div>
  <script src="directions.js"></script>
  <script>
    function initialize() {
      var markerArray = [];
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: {
          lat: 22.771,
          lng: 88.974
        }
      });

      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map
      });
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, map);

      var onChangeHandler = function() {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, map);
      };

      //document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
      //document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    }


    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, map) {

      for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
        markerArray[i].setMap(null);
      }

      for (pos in MarketInfo) {
        var row = MarketInfo[pos];
        // Second loop for multiple destination
        var str_array = row[7].split(',');
        for (var j = 0; j < str_array.length; j++) {
          directionsService.route({
            origin: str_array[j],
            destination: row[1],
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
          }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
              document.getElementById('warnings-panel').innerHTML = '<b>' + response.routes[0].warnings + '</b>';
              var dirDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                 map: map
              });
              dirDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
              window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBbXta5ppMyzPmTCGNsyP-djMlSOGJ9t9o&callback=initialize">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked like a charm.!